# Does "a coward" have the same meaning as "not brave"?

Tags: adjectives

> The difference is that **cowardly** is usually an adjective, while **coward** is almost always a noun. Hence:
>
> > That dog is a coward.
> >
> > That cowardly dog runs at the sound of hooves.
>
> ...
>
> [the link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/usage-of-cowardly-and-coward)

I couldn't understand how "coward" is noun in "That dog is a coward.", let's take the word **brave** as example:

> That dog is **brave**.

Is brave an adjective in this sentence? If yes, so why is "coward" noun in the same clause structure?

if "coward" word is a none in "That dog is a coward", Does it has any difference meaning than:

> That dog is **not brave**.

Another question: Can we remove the article "a"? is this make it adjective? Does it still has the same meaning?

Comment: The fact that either an adjective or a noun can appear after a "to be" verb is illustrated by this classic "Dad joke": "I'm hungry." "Hi Hungry, I'm Dad."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice the indefinite article before "coward". Indefinite articles almost always introduce noun phrases.

> The dog is **a** coward.

"a coward" is called a noun phrase, functioning as the [predicative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement).

> The dog is brave.

"brave" is an **adjective phrase**, consisting of only one word, functioning as the predicative complement.

---

Whether "not brave" is the same as "cowardly" is debatable. You can argue that the dog is not cowardly, but isn't brave either; i.e. there's a middle ground.

[image]

Note that this is just an illustration. There's no way to quantify cowardliness.

Comment: Thank you, can we omit "a", "That dog is coward.", Is it now adjective?

Comment: @Shannak see [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/usage-of-cowardly-and-coward); TL;DR; no, we can't omit it. "coward" as an adjective only appears in the attributive position, that is, right before nouns.

Comment: Following M.A.R 's note: the words *coward* and *cowardly* are properly used of people who fail to do their duty out of fear - frequently of soldiers at war. To be frightened is not to be cowardly. A jackal that runs away from a carcass when a lion approaches is not a cowardly animal, but a sensible one. There's no point in getting a hiding for nothing.

Comment: there seems to be a 'feature' in english where if you say that someone/something is "not X", it actually implies that they "are the opposite of X". "not brave" then becomes synonymous with "is a coward".

Comment: @Sahuagin that's context-dependent. Sometimes context rules out the middle ground. But without any context, we can't rule it out. And I don't think it's restricted to English.

Comment: Is it context-dependent? Something I can never figure out is how *not* to have that implication.

Comment: @Sahuagin That might be because you only either have binary states or the two extremes in mind. If the door isn't open, it must be closed. But if a surface isn't smooth, it could be rough, or it could be something between smooth and rough, in a way that qualifies neither adjective in your mind.

Comment: @Sahuagin For context, consider "He's not a brave dog—he hides under the bed during thunderstorms, and runs away from the cat. But he fought off the housebreaker who threatened me."

Comment: A “coward” is one who responds to threat in a manner that is considered shameful.  Etymology is derived from the (now) archaic “to cow”, from which we have more contemporary words like “to cower” — e.g. ‘cowering in the face of adversity’.  But, I don't think this is topical.

Comment: @1006a thanks, that is a good example, using "not X, but ..."

Comment: @ruakh I welcome alternate wordings. We can argue that "dog" is a noun and thus that's a noun phrase, but "very big" is indeed an adjective phrase. What about "Indefinite articles can't appear right before adjective phrases when the next phrase consists of a single word."? It's restricted, but we don't need to come up with universally applicable rules anyway.

Comment: Hmm, sounds good. Let me edit. I'm still forty percent asleep. :)